# Spark - Difference between sortBy and sortByKey

Tags: apache-spark

What is the difference between `sortBy` and `sortByKey` functions in Spark?

I am performing this below transformation in which i am using sortBy & sortByKey. Both are giving the same results then what is the difference in that.

```scala
val reducedSfpd = sfpd.map(x => (x(col_2),1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)

val top3Dist = reducedSfpd.sortBy(_._2,false).collect().take(3)    
val top3Dist = reducedSfpd.map(x => x.swap).sortByKey(false).take(3)
```

Is there any performance related difference between sortBy && sortByKey.

In fact when I am using `sortBy` I am saving one transformation of swapping the 'Key - Values' by applying map function. Then why `sortByKey`?

Answer (score 9):

> In fact when I am using sortBy I am saving one transformation of swapping the 'Key - Values' by applying map function.

You don't. In practice you add an additional transformation and slightly increase network traffic on the way. `sortBy` `maps` input RDD to `(f(x), x)` pairs, applies `sortByKey` and finally takes `values`. I doubt it will impact the performance but it is certainly something to remember.

While using `sortBy` makes your intentions a little bit more obvious `sortByKey` outputs partitioned RDD what can be useful for downstream processing.

On a side note I would use neither `sortBy` nor `sortByKey` to extract top elements. Instead it is better to choose `top`

```
reducedSfpd.top(3)(Ordering.by[(K, Int), Int](-_._2))
```

or `takeOrdered`

```
reducedSfpd.takeOrdered(3)(Ordering.by[(String, Int), Int](_._2))
```

with specific ordering where `K` is a type of the key.